# Failed to load resource when I implemented one sveltekit project in Google Cloud Run with custom domain

Tags: svelte, google-cloud-run, svelte-3, sveltekit

Describe the bug:
I use Google Cloud Run to run my svelte kit app with the node adapter.
It seems to work with the default version but with my custom domain it can not load the resources in the [slug].svelte routes.

Default version:

```
https://youernes-22w6ta6irq-ew.a.run.app/yhoyquetoca
https://youernes-22w6ta6irq-ew.a.run.app/planes/UEVytEBG6rfcLrdqflD8TsjmCRn2_1611080173358
```

Custom domain version:

```
https://youernes.com/yhoyquetoca
https://youernes.com/planes/UEVytEBG6rfcLrdqflD8TsjmCRn2_1602059251917
```

In the custom domain version I can not access to information though It can fetch data from script module.

I use the node adapter and this is my following configuration:

```
const sveltePreprocess = require("svelte-preprocess");
    const node = require('@sveltejs/adapter-node');
    const pkg = require('./package.json');

    /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
    module.exports = {
        preprocess: [
            sveltePreprocess({
                defaults: {
                    style: "postcss",
                },
                postcss: true
            }),
        ],
        kit: {
            hostHeader: 'X-Forwarded-Host',
            // By default, `npm run build` will create a standard Node app.
            // You can create optimized builds for different platforms by
            // specifying a different adapter
            adapter: node(),

            // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
            target: '#svelte',

            vite: {
                ssr: {
                    noExternal: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

1st I run
npm run build

and
2nd I use docker

> FROM node:12.17
>
> WORKDIR /youernes
>
> ENV PORT=8080
>
> ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
>
> COPY . .
>
> CMD [ "node" , "build/" ]

When I access to planes folder I get the following errors:

```
GET https://youernes.com/_app/pages/planes/[slug].svelte-098e0796.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://youernes.com/_app/assets/pages/planes/[slug].svelte-377bb070.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://youernes.com/_app/pages/planes/[slug].svelte-098e0796.js

TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://youernes.com/_app/pages/planes/[slug].svelte-098e0796.js
```

How to reproduce the problem in order to get the solution:
You have to implement with node adapter one svelte kit project with [slug].svelte routes and then implemented it using google cloud run with custom domain.
Can someone help me or even tried this?

Thank you very much to all.

Comment: Try "npm install" first on your build image? Do you have a log entry from your docker what "node build/" serves?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the issue through mapping custom domains on google cloud run